# How to compare elements of two arrays in assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, emu8086

I need to solve the following problem:
I need to put 4 arrays in memory, each array has 10 numbers which are the size of one byte.
Now, I need to find the way to check if any of the numbers from one string have a pair in another string and if they do I need to put those answers on to stack.

This is what I did so far:

```
arr1 db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
arr2 db 2, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
arr3 db 1, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
arr4 db 1, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37

lea si, arr1
lea di, arr2
mov al, 0
mov bl, 0

mov cx, 10
loopOne:
    loopTwo: 
        cmp [si+al],[di+bl]
        je done
        inc al
        loop loopTwo
    inc bl
    mov al, 0    
loop loopOne 
done: 
mov dl, si+al
inc 21h
ret
```

I'm using emu8086.

EDIT:

This is how it'd look like in Java:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int[] arr2 = { 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};
        int[] arr3 = { 1, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28};
        int[] arr4 =  { 1, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37 };
        int a = 0; //counter of matches in every pair of arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length ; i++) {
            for( int j = 0; j < arr2.length ; j++){
                if( arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
        //instead of printing, the number of matches ( a ) should be pushed on to stack
        System.out.println("Number of matches: " + a);
        a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length ; i++) {
            for( int j = 0; j < arr3.length ; j++){
                if( arr1[i] == arr3[j]){
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of matches: " + a);
        a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length ; i++) {
            for( int j = 0; j < arr4.length ; j++){
                if( arr1[i] == arr4[j]){
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of matches: " + a);
        a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length ; i++) {
            for( int j = 0; j < arr3.length ; j++){
                if( arr2[i] == arr3[j]){
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of matches: " + a);
        a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length ; i++) {
            for( int j = 0; j < arr4.length ; j++){
                if( arr2[i] == arr4[j]){
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of matches: " + a);
        a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr3.length ; i++) {
            for( int j = 0; j < arr4.length ; j++){
                if( arr3[i] == arr4[j]){
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of matches: " + a);
        a = 0;


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add some java code demostrating what you're trying to do. It's still not clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LOOP` is designed for small and simple loops. Things become complicated when it is used for longer calculations or for nested loops.  I suggest to avoid `LOOP` in those cases.

`cmp [si+al],[di+bl]` is wrong. You cannot compare two values in memory in this way. The so called string operations (`scas`, `movs`, `cmps`) are uncomfortable to handle in a 16-bit environment (MS-DOS) and especially for this task. Furthermore, you cannot add a WORD (`si`) and a BYTE (`bl`).

I figured out the first comparison (`arr1`/`arr2`) for you and hope you can add the remaining comparisons by yourself.

```
.MODEL small
.STACK

include "emu8086.inc"

.DATA
    arr1 db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    arr2 db 2, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
    arr3 db 1, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
    arr4 db 1, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37


.CODE
define_print_num_uns            ; emu8086.inc


start:
    mov ax, @data               ; Initialize DS
    mov ds, ax

    ; Compare arr1 and arr2
    lea si, arr1                ; Reset pointer to arr1
    mov cl, 10                  ; Length of arr1 = loop counter for loopOne
    mov bx, 0                   ; Counter for matches
    loopOne:                    ; Loop through arr1
        mov al, [si]            ; Load one element of arr1
        lea di, arr2            ; Reset pointer to arr2
        mov ch, 10              ; Length of arr2 = loop counter for loopTwo
        loopTwo:                ; Loop through arr2
            mov ah, [di]        ; Load one element of arr2
            cmp al, ah          ; Compare it
            jne @1              ; Skip the next line if no match
            inc bx              ; Increment match counter
            @1:
            inc di              ; Next element in arr2
            dec ch              ; Decrement loop counter
            jne loopTwo         ; Loop - break if CH == 0
        inc si                  ; Next elemnt in arr1
        dec cl                  ; Decrement loop counter
        jne loopOne             ; Loop - break if CL == 0
    mov ax, bx                  ; match counter into AX for print_num_uns
    call print_num_uns          ; emu8086.inc

    mov ax, 4C00h               ; MS-DOS function 4C: Exit program
    int 21h                     ; Call MS-DOS

end start
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I finished the rest. I appreciate the detailed comments.
It's just unclear to me what exactly '@data' does?

Comment: @Pantokrator: The most instruvtions that operate on memory (e.g `mov al, [si]`) use implicitely the segment register `DS` for addressing.  At program start, `DS` hasn't the right value. `@data`is a short form for `segment of the .DATA section`. `mov ds, ax` loads that address to `DS`. This is called "initializing DS".

Comment: Certainly a good answer (+1) but I don't get why the string operations would be __uncomfortable to handle in an MS-DOS environment__. I have never had any troubles using them under any DOS.

Comment: @Fifoernik: Thanks for the upvote. Maybe my English is too bad. "Uncomfortable" doesn't mean "impossible". I have no doubt that an expert can handle `REP`, `ES:DI`, `DS:SI`, `AL & CX`, `ZF & DF` without getting trouble. - and can easily reply to the  objection "obsolete CISC instruction".  So do I. Please read my statement in the context *"You cannot compare two values in memory"*. Frankly, I needed a reason why I advised against a string instruction in this case. Feel free to suitably improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking too much from x86 assembly.
In any given instruction there can be only one memory operand.

Your `cmp [si+al],[di+bl]` has two and will thus not assemble.
Also you're using `cx` as a loop counter for 2 loops. That will not work. After the first loop is finished `cx` will be 0, aka 65536, meaning the outer loop+inner loop will run 64k times (oops).

Because your intent is unclear I can't really help you with the details of the code.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, I need to solve the following problem:
I need to put 4 arrays in memory, each array has 10 numbers which are the size of one byte. I only need to put those numbers in memory, there is no need for me to enter data from keyboard.
Now, I need to find the way to check if any of the numbers from one string have a pair in another string and if they do I need to put those answers on to stack.

I program in Java and whenever I had to compare two arrays I had to use two loops. I'm used to different way of thinking and coding.

Comment: It's not like you shouldn't use two loops, the point is that you cannot use the same register for both - or, if you do, you have to save/restore it. There's no such a thing as lexical scoping in assembly, if you overwrite a register in an inner loop it will keep that value even in the outer loop.